# How should we parse this proof that every infinite set has a subset which is eqivalent to the set of natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, natural-numbers, transfinite-recursion

This is again from the chapter *Construction of the System of Real Numbers* in [The Fundamentals of Mathematics, Volume 1](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/fundamentals-mathematics-3-vol-set).  It may be the case that the original wording in the German language would be easier to follow.  As it stands, I'm not exactly sure how to break down the following (half) paragraph.

> In general, two sets are said to be equivalent if either of them can
>   be mapped one-to-one onto the other. Thus the finite sets are defined
>   as those sets that are equivalent to the segments $A_{n}.$ For convenience,
>   the empty set $\emptyset,$ which contains no elements at all, is
>   also said to be a finite set. In an infinite set $M,$ namely a set
>   which is not finite, it is easy to determine a set which is equivalent
>   to the set $\mathbb{N}$ of all natural numbers: for if $f$ is a
>   mapping which to each non-empty subset $X$ of the set $M$ assigns
>   an element of $f\left[X\right]$ of the subset $X,$ the sets $M_{1},M_{2},\dots$
>   can be defined recursively by $M_{1}=\left\{ f\left[M\right]\right\} ,$$M_{n^{\prime}}=M_{n}\cup\left\{ f\left[M-M_{n}\right]\right\} ,$
>   and then the union of the $M_{n}$ provides us with the desired subset
>   $\mathbb{N^{*}}.$

The part I'm not sure about is:

*$\dots$ if $f$ is a mapping which to each non-empty subset $X$ of the set $M$ assigns an element of $f\left[X\right]$ of the subset $X,$ $\dots$*

In particular, am I supposed to understand $f\left[X\right]$ to be a set?  That's what I would typically make of the phrase "an element of $f\left[X\right]$."  But that would mean, for example, that $M_{1}=\left\{ f\left[M\right]\right\}$ is a nested set, and therefore $\left[M-M_{1}\right]=M$ since $M$ has no elements which are sets.

Could the "of" in "an element of $f\left[X\right]$" be dropped or replaced by "designated by", or something similar?

It is also unclear what it means to assign $f\left[X\right]$ to the set $X$.

How might we reword the entire passage:

> if $f$ is a
>   mapping which to each non-empty subset $X$ of the set $M$ assigns
>   an element of $f\left[X\right]$ of the subset $X,$ the sets $M_{1},M_{2},\dots$
>   can be defined recursively by $M_{1}=\left\{ f\left[M\right]\right\} ,$ $M_{n^{\prime}}=M_{n}\cup\left\{ f\left[M-M_{n}\right]\right\} ,$
>   and then the union of the $M_{n}$ provides us with the desired subset
>   $\mathbb{N^{*}}.$,

to be clearer?  I'm trying, but it isn't as easy as it seems.

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that "of" is a typo, and shouldn't be there.

Comment: The wording is still difficult if "of" is dropped.  I'm pretty sure what is intended, but I don't believe the intent is actually stated.

Comment: No, it works fine without the "of": $f$ is just a choice function: for every element $Y$ of the power set of $X$, it produces an element of $Y$. Each $M_n$, then, is a subset of $X$ with exactly $n$ elements, and $n \mapsto M_n$ gives a one-to-one onto mapping from $\mathbb{N}$ to a subset of $X$.

Comment: I guess the interpretation hinges on the definition of "assign to".  I don't know that assignment has a clear mathematical definition.  In computer programming it means to give a value to a variable.  I think I should modify my question.

Comment: It does: "$f$ assigns $x$ to $y$" just means that $f$ takes the value $x$ when given the input $y$.

Comment: But the quote says that $f\left[X\right]$ is assigned to $X$.  Please see my updated question.

Comment: If $X$ is a set and $f$ is a function (mapping) then $f[X]$ is taken to mean the set $\{f(x)|x \in X\}$.  So for example if $f(x) = x^2 -2x + 3$ and $S = \{1,2, 5,8,9\}$ then $f[S] = \{2, 3, 18, 51,66\}$.

Comment: @fleablood That's annoyingly not how it's being used here - "$f(S)$" would be better notation here. (See the details of the question.)

Comment: @fleablood that won't work in this context.  $f$ is a mapping from the power set of $M$ into the set $M$.  Apparently "assigns to" means that $f$ is a set of ordered pairs the first element of which is an element of the power set of $M$, and the second element is a member the first element.  And there is only one such pair for each element of the power set.

Comment: @StevenHatton Minor correction: "And there is only one such pair for each [**nonempty**] element of the power set."

Comment: @StevenHatton Yes, exactly: $f$ assigns $f[X]$ to $X$. To the element (of the powerset) $X$, $f[X]$ assigns the element (of $X$) $f[X]$, which is just any element of $X$ [note that we're using the axiom of choice here].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your own translation? To get it to make sense, all you need to do is replace

> an element of $f[X]$ of the subset $X$

with

> an element $f[X]$ of the subset $X$

Comment: I guess if I take "assigns to" to mean "associates with", then I can accept the answer.

Comment: @StevenHatton: I think it is reasonable to say that a function $h:A\rightarrow B$ assigns an element of $B$ to each element of $A$.

Comment: "Assigns to" is indeed accepted language here, @StevenHatton.

Answer (score 0):

$f[X]$ is an **element of** $M$ (when $X$ is a nonempty subset of $M$). That is, $$f:\mathcal{P}_{\not=\emptyset}(M)\rightarrow M.$$ This means that $M-M_1$ is *not* just $M$, since $M=\{f[M]\}$ is a set containing a single element of $M$.

---

I think it's helpful to first consider a specific example: if we take $M=\{1,2,3,...\}$ and $f[X]=\min(X)$ *(note that this fits the rule: $f$ is indeed defined on every nonempty subset of $M$, and sends a nonempty subset of $M$ to an element of that subset)*, then:

- $M_1=\{f[M]\}=\{\min(\{1,2,3,...\})\}=\{1\}$.
- $M_2=M_1\cup \{f[M\setminus M_1]\}=\{1\}\cup\min(\{2,3,4,...\})=\{1,2\}.$
- And in general, $M_k=\{1,2,...,k\}$.

Comment: My problem is not that I don't understand what is meant.  I'm trying to restate it in closed form.  Part of my difficulty is not having notation for the operation of choice, if that's what it's called.

Comment: I think you mean $f[X]$ is an element of $X$, not $M$.

Comment: $X$ is a subset of $M$ so $f\left[X\right]\in{X}\implies{f\left[X\right]\in{M}}$

Comment: @StevenHatton What do you mean by "closed form"?

Comment: @TonyK I meant what I wrote, although you're correct - I just wanted to emphasize that the types "match up."

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ideally, that means to either express it entirely using predicates, quantifiers, variables, logical connectives, etc.  At this point I understand it well enough to leave it for my next review cycle, so I haven't put a lot of effort into formulating the statement, but what got me stuck was a concise way of codifying the idea that $f$ selects exactly one element of $X$.  It might be sufficient to simply write $\mathcal{P}_{\ne\emptyset}\left[M\right]\to M$ meaning  a surjection, and then further qualify it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I forgot the "or".  Or put it into words that easily translate into purely symbolic expressions.

Comment: @StevenHatton $f$ doesn't have to be a surjection, the requirement is just that $f$ is a function from $\mathcal{P}_{\not=\emptyset}(M)$ to $M$ such that $f(X)\in X$ for all $X\in\mathcal{P}_{\not=\emptyset}(M)$. Incidentally, I *strongly* prefer circle braces over square braces in these contexts (see fleablood's comment below your answer for why). (And personally I think that the definition given above *does* easily translate into a purely symbolic expression - how would you prefer it to be phrased? - but I suppose that's subjective.)

Comment: Would you consider "Let $f:\mathcal{P}_{\not=\emptyset}(M)\rightarrow M$ be such that $f(X)\in X$ for all $X\in\mathcal{P}_{\not=\emptyset}(M)$" sufficiently closed-form?

Comment: (@StevenHatton Clarifying the first sentence of two comments ago: clearly such an $f$ will be a surjection, since we must always have $f(\{m\})=m$ for $m\in M$; what I meant was that we don't *use in the argument* that $f$ is a surjection. So $f$ does have to be a surjection, but not because we need it to be, just because surjectivity falls out of the requirement we *do* actually need.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I had to move on from this problem, but I wanted to address my unconventional use of $'\left[''\right]'$ brackets.  I find it preferable to distinguish between parameter lists and precedence indicators.  One thing worse than nonstandard usage is inconsistent usage.  To the extent that nonstandard notation might be considered rude, I prefer to be consistently rude than inconsistently polite.  I am learning that there is a collision between my notation and the use of square brackets in abstract algebra.  I will try to clarify my where where it seems necessary.